# react-table v7 dynamic columns and rows from a json data from an api

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-table-v7

I am new to react. I have a json api which I need to display as a table in client side. I want to use react-table v7. My idea is:

- Take the keys from the data as column Headers and Accessor
- The json data are the rows

I have a table component, it takes the headers and data as props, kindly look below:

```
import React from 'react';
import { useTable } from 'react-table'

const Table = ({
  headers,
  items
}) => {
  function getColumns() {
    if (headers) {
    return headers.map(key => {
      return {

        Header: key.toString(),
        accessor: key.toString()
      };
    });
  }}

const columns = React.useMemo(() => [
    getColumns()
  ],
  []
  )

const data = React.useMemo(() => [
  items
], []
) 

const {
  getTableProps,
  getTableBodyProps,
  headerGroups,
  rows,
  prepareRow,
} = useTable({ columns, data })

return (
  <table {...getTableProps()} style={{ border: 'solid 1px blue' }}>
  <thead>
    {headerGroups.map(headerGroup => (
      <tr {...headerGroup.getHeaderGroupProps()}>
        {headerGroup.headers.map(column => (
          <th
            {...column.getHeaderProps()}
            style={{
              borderBottom: 'solid 3px red',
              background: 'aliceblue',
              color: 'black',
              fontWeight: 'bold',
            }}
          >
            {column.render('Header')}
          </th>
        ))}
      </tr>
    ))}
  </thead>
  <tbody {...getTableBodyProps()}>
    {rows.map(row => {
      prepareRow(row)
      return (
        <tr {...row.getRowProps()}>
          {row.cells.map(cell => {
            return (
              <td
                {...cell.getCellProps()}
                style={{
                  padding: '10px',
                  border: 'solid 1px gray',
                  background: 'papayawhip',
                }}
              >
                {cell.render('Cell')}
              </td>
            )
          })}
        </tr>
      )
    })}
  </tbody>
</table>
  )
}



export default Table;
```

Then I have another component to make get request via axios and set columns and data from its response and import the Table component to pass the props define here, code below:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import Table from './Table'
import axios from 'axios'


export const STable = () => {

const [columns, setColumns] = useState([])
const [rows, setRows] = useState([])

const getData = () => {
    axios.get("http://localhost:5001/")
    .then(res => {
        console.log(res.data)
        setColumns({ columns: Object.keys(res.data[0]) })
        setRows({ rows: res.data })
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
    })
}

useEffect(() => {
    getData()
}, [] )

return (
    <div>
        <Table headers={columns} items={rows} />
    </div>
)
}

export default Stable;
```

Finally the App component

```
import React from 'react';
import STable from './components/STable';


function App() {
return (
<div>
  
  <STable/>
</div>

 );
}

export default App;
```

However I get this error, see pic,

[image]

I do not know where I am doing wrong. I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have id field in all columns with accessors. In your code you need to set id field for every inner column like that.

```
return headers.map(key => {
      return {
        id: key toString(),
        Header: key.toString(),
        accessor: key.toString()
      };
    });
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for your answer, I already tried the same and it didn't work